how to remove zeros after rounding in DAX?
I would like to round 18,846,888 as 18,847. While ROUNDUP(18,846,888, 3)  generates 18,847,000.
my Expected Answer 18,847K

Divide by 1000 before rounding.

Measure  = FORMAT( 18846888, "#,0,K")

